# Keycloak SSO (SAML) with SpringBoot API and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect, saml-2.0

I am developing an application which has APIs developed in JAVA SpringBoot. These are pure REST APIs.
The frontend is developed in React.

I am supposed to add authentication in React in such a way that - it uses Keycloak as IDP for user authentication before accessing SpringBoot APIs.

So far, I have seen that Keycloak can support keycloak.js which is JavaScript adapter for OPEN ID connect. But I want the solution for SAML 2.0.

**Is there a way I can add SAML 2.0 SSO in React app?**

Also one more question:

- Application A is configured with SAML as authentication protocol in keycloak.
- Application B is configured with OPEN ID connect as authentication protocol in keycloak and has permission to access Application A.

If a user authenticates to application B using OpenID connect and then tries to access Application A, will user be able to access Application A seamlessly or it will ask for authenticate again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle authentication in your Spring Boot backend not in the react frontend (see: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml) because SAML is only an authentication mechanism, it does not provide authorization like OpenId (there's no access token).

When the user is authorized, you could give back a session cookie to your react app that will provide the necessary information to authorize future API requests to your backend.

As for your second question, you could find a way to use the SAML assertion you used to connect to application A to retrieve an access token for Application B.

There is a specification for this kind of mechanism: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-20

Bear in mind that this would imply a lot of custom implementation work, you would be better to use OpenId across all your apps in order to have SSO for your users.

Comment: @idclrcq - The problem is - my current Spring Boot is pure REST API and React is on separate app. i.e. These two are on separate domains. Per your suggestion, I will have to combine these two into one single domain and then render the react app from SpringBoot.

Comment: About my question - later yesterday, I did this experiment and I was able to seamlessly navigate between the application so I guess those two works fine.

Comment: I was suggesting to redirect to spring boot only for the authentication process. You can of course keep your frontend and backend separate.

Comment: @idclrcq - Can you help me understand exactly how that will work?
a) User clicks on sign-in button on frontend (react)
b) User gets redirected to SSO login
c) User submits credential
d) SSO submits assertion to web API backend

e) How will use get redirect to app again?
f) How the backend will share the token with frontend?

Comment: @HirenDesai did u manage to solve this issue? I am stuck here as well. How will the frontend (react) know what is the token that was received by the Authorization flow on the backend? Our apps are on two different domains (backend & frontend)

Comment: @sem10 - Yes, I ignored the SAML. It does not work. I used OPEN ID connect to authenticate against the backend.